# Upgrading to Capistrano 3: prompt with 'translation missing: en.capistrano.questio' when running deploy:check

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, capistrano, locale

I'm in the process of upgrading an app from Rails 3 to Rails 4. In the process, I left capistrano at version 2 since that is a hefty upgrade on its own and now I'm getting to that.

The issue I'm currently seeing is that when I run `cap production deploy:check` the process halts at the spot that should be asking for the branch to be deployed and shows this:

```
translation missing: en.capistrano.question
```

I'm pretty sure this is coming from the following line in my `deploy.rb`:

```
ask :branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }
```

I have worked on other apps with cap 3 and I remember this line having some line prompting for a branch to deploy with the current branch in parentheses.

I looked in one of those apps' `locale.yml` file and couldn't find `en.capistrano.question`. Anyone know what I need to do to get the correct prompt, or if I'm looking in the wrong place for this problem?